# Read CallLog for a Specific Contact (with contact ID)

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, calllog

I have to show a "Recent Activity" for a contact in my Android App. So I need to read all incoming, outgoing and all type of calls for that contact. I need to do that with Contact ID(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID).

I can read all CallLog and then Search that list for that specific ID, but it is very slow. So I think I need a custom Cursor for to do that. I tried to write a cursor but it is not working right now.

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    CallLog.Calls._ID+" = ?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(148)},
    null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need.

```
Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(148)}, null, null);
    if (contact != null && contact.moveToNext()) {
        String lookupKey = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        int contactId = contact.getInt(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);

        Cursor calls = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_LOOKUP_URI + "=?", new String[]{contactUri.toString()}, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        while (calls.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "type: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) + ", number: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)) + ", " + "cached_name: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)) + ", " + "date: " + calls.getString(calls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of Course. But there is one thing. I tested your method more and I found It does not returns some of my contacts. I couldn't find reason. What do you think what could be ? There is no error or anything, it just cant find the contact.

Comment: Do you save the contact id to a database and then retrieve it at a later time or you get the contact id from the Contacts provider just before you run the CallLog provider query?

Comment: I get the contact ID just before run the algorithm you wrote.

Comment: Any ideas for <API 21?